# Cross-communication not working in Microfrontend using React

Tags: reactjs, redux, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have two React MF apps built using create-mf-app. One is Container app MF1. Other is Login app MF2.

I am using Redux to store data.

The global store is in Container app  MF1.

I want to set data in global store after login.

On accessing  the login app in Container MF1, I am able to store the data. While the same thing is not happening after logging via Login app MF2.

Below is the code snippet :

The global store and actions are created in MF1.

```
This is the reducer file in MF1.
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  token: 'null',
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
    saveToken: (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload
    },
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { saveToken } = counterSlice.actions

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

I am able to access the global state 'token'  in MF1.

This is how I am accessing it in MF1.

```
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.token)
```

The function below in MF1 :

```
export function useGetInstance(method, path, body = "", customConfig = {}) {

  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.token)
```

This function I am using in MF2 and there I am getting the value of count as null.

```
  let config = useGetInstance("GET", prefix + "/setup/user/", "");

  console.log("config is:",config)
```